# Creating a stripe subscription with a loyalty/tiered discount

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

I'm trying to create a subscription in stripe which depending on how long people have been subscribed the price per month goes down e.g.:

```
1st month 1000$ 
2nd,3rd,4th month 800$ 
5-9 months 750$
9-12 600$
< 12 500$
```

I looked into tiered discounts but couldn't find a relation to the single subscription price since tiered discount seems to only look at currently subscribed units, and not total volume of units since subscription started. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by [listening for upcoming invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/webhooks#tracking) and then [changing the Plan](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrading-downgrading) on the Subscription based on how long the Subscription has been active.

Another option is to use [Subscription Schedules](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules).

Comment: That's a great answer, sure to change my issues! Thanks a lot!